# Behavior of 'cd --' (two hyphens)

Tags: bash, cd

I know that `cd ~-` changes directory to $OLDPWD.

I'm using `GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0)` on a Macbook.

'cd --' appears to have the same behavior as 'cd ~-'.

Why?

Comment: Not sure if its dupe worthy - but I believe this posts contains the information you seek - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330876/difference-between-cd-and-cd

Comment: Oh... you're right, @winston - I was sure I saw a `--` in there somewhere... Apologies for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not correct. `cd --` changes to your home directory, just like `cd` only. Consider `cd --` a pure `cd` with no options and no parameters given. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382.

Comment: Wow I just completely brain-farted there. You are right.

Answer (score 5):

With Bash `--` is used to specify the end of a command options.

So `cd --` means `cd`.

`cd` without argument change your current directory to your home directory (like `cd ~`).

The fact it leads you to your last PWD is a coincidence.

Comment: +1, but I think you'd call it "end of command options" instead of "end of command line". You can specify more command arguments (parameters) after `--`.